# desktop notifications in service

Tags: python, notifications, windows-services, desktop

I wrote a **python program** that get messages from server and invokes windows notification.

I turned the program into a one file **executable** using pyinstaller, the program works perfect when running as an **app**.

when I turned it into a **service** on windows 10 using nssm.exe, the service still works well(listen & response to the server) but **the notifications do not displayed.**

I tried to

- allow service interact with desktop under the service properties > log on.
- change the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>SYSTEM>CurrentControlSet>Control>Windows>NoInteractiveService = 0(False)

Is there anything else I can try to solve this problem?

Edit - the program works great (communication & notification) as a script(.py), and as an executable(.exe), the problem is that the notification do not displayed when the executable is running as a service using nssm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Services run in the background, on the [isolated Session 0](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/ba-p/372361). Their GUI elements (tray icons, windows) will not show up on your interactive desktop.

In previous versions of Windows, you could switch to Session 0 to see your application's windows (though not it's tray icon). However, [access to Session 0 has been removed in Windows 10](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/interactive-services-removed-windows-10/).

Comment: heard about that, may be the problem.
I tried to set my service as user service and not system service, still cant see the notifications, do you know a workaround or something?

Comment: Running your service in a user account will make no difference. There is no workaround for what you are trying to achieve. The isolation of Session 0 was introduced to prevent "shatter attacks" -- a serious security problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the python module ***win10toast*** or ***wintoast***

Links: -

- [wintoast](https://pypi.org/project/wintoast/)
- [win10toast](https://pypi.org/project/win10toast/)

[Here's a related video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KRKLkZTY7SE)

Hope it solves your problem!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but its irrelevant.
the program works well, connects and listens to a remote server using sockets, the notification done with win10toast-click(with callback functions).
when the program running as a script(.py) - everything works fine (communication & notifications)
when the program run as an app(.exe) - everything works fine (communication & notifications)
when the program run as a service(nssm) - the communication works fine (I can see the ack msg in the remote server, but the notification do not display on the screen)

Comment: This is because it works on Windows only (wintoast)... When it runs as a service, it does not import dependencies which are available in Windows(10) and thus, it throws an error. Although, I doubt it'll help, buts its worth a try - **Try searching a nssm notification workaround/plugin of win10toast...** Or maybe look for something else then... (Sorry I couldn't help)